# CI - Call to a member function error - why?

Tags: function, codeigniter

I'm getting a "Call to a member function get_group() on a non-object in views/join_group_form.php" error and have no idea what I'm missing here...

The join_group_form.php has this code:

```
echo "Join group: " . $groupid;
$query1 = $this->site_model->get_group($groupid);
foreach($query1 as $r1) :
    echo $r1->group_name;
endforeach;
```

$groupid is passed from the controller as part of an array, it echo's the $groupid fine on the first line but I'm guessing for whatever reason, it's not accepting it in the call to the $this->site_model->get_group($groupid)

The site_model function it refers to is this:

```
public function get_group($id)
{
    // Get rows from DB
    $query = $this->db->get_where($this->groups, array('group_id' => $id));
    // Check if at least 1 row is returned and pass to array
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

I've used very similar code on another part of my site and it all works fine so don't understand why this errors, any help appreciated!

Comment: have you loaded the model prior to calling it?

Comment: Oh lol, no I hadn't, I'm such a dumbass, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you loaded the model prior to calling it?